# A query that lists all mapped users for a given login

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, permissions, security, logins

When looking at the properties of a particular login, it's possible to see a list of users mapped to that login:
[image]

I profiled SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and I see that SSMS connects to every database one at a time and retrieves information from sys.database_permissions

Is it possible to write a single query that retrieves the user mapping information shown above or am I forced to use a cursor or sp_MSforeachdb or something like that?

Comment: Please [don't use sp_MSforeachdb](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's one way using dynamic SQL. There's not really any way to do this without iterating, but this approach is much safer than undocumented, unsupported and buggy options like `sp_MSforeachdb` (background [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5686/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server-using-spineachdb/) and [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/)).

This will get a list of all online databases, the mapped user (if it exists), along with the default schema name, and a comma-separated list of the roles they belong to.

```
DECLARE @name sysname = N'your login name'; -- input param, presumably

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'UNION ALL SELECT N''' + REPLACE(name,'''','''''') + ''',
    p.name                 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, 
    p.default_schema_name  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, 
    STUFF((SELECT N'','' + r.name 
      FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + N'.sys.database_principals AS r
      INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(name) + N'.sys.database_role_members AS rm
      ON r.principal_id = rm.role_principal_id
      WHERE rm.member_principal_id = p.principal_id
      FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value(N''.[1]'',''nvarchar(max)''),1,1,N'''')
    FROM sys.server_principals AS sp
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.database_principals AS p
    ON sp.sid = p.sid
    WHERE sp.name = @name '
  FROM sys.databases WHERE [state] = 0;

SET @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, 9, N'');

PRINT @sql;
EXEC master.sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@name sysname', @name;
```

On more modern versions (2017+), I would still use dynamic SQL, but I would use `STRING_AGG()` instead of `FOR XML PATH`, probably something like this:

```
DECLARE @login sysname = N'your login name';

DECLARE @sql  nvarchar(max), 
        @sid  varbinary(85),
        @coll nvarchar(64) = N'COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS';

SELECT @sid = [sid] FROM sys.server_principals AS dp WHERE name = @login;

;WITH d AS 
(
  SELECT dbid = CONVERT(varchar(11), database_id),
         qn = QUOTENAME(name)
    FROM sys.databases WHERE [state] = 0
)
SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG(CONVERT(nvarchar(max),
        N'SELECT db = d.name, username = dp.name ' + @coll + ', 
        schemaname = dp.default_schema_name ' + @coll + ',
        roles = STRING_AGG(rp.name ' + @coll + ', N'','')
        FROM sys.databases AS d
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ' + qn + '.sys.database_principals AS dp ON dp.sid = @sid
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ' + qn + '.sys.database_role_members AS rm
        ON dp.principal_id = rm.member_principal_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ' + qn + '.sys.database_principals AS rp
        ON rp.principal_id = rm.role_principal_id
        WHERE d.database_id = ' + dbid + N'
        GROUP BY d.name, dp.name, dp.default_schema_name'
    ), char(13) + char(10) + N' UNION ALL ')
FROM d;

PRINT @sql;
EXEC master.sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@sid varbinary(85)', @sid;
```

In this latter example, if you only want the databases with a user mapped to the named login, just change the first left join to an inner join.

Comment: interesting note, I had to add explicit collations to p.name and p.default_schema_name columns for the union all to work properly

Comment: @MichaelJSwart Ah yes, I've come across this before when databases have different collations (some metadata columns use the server collation but others inherit the database collation). I hope the only people that really ever burns are those that insist on using wacky characters in entity names that are only supported in some obscure collation...

Answer (score 7):

This script is slightly modified from a script mentioned at will do what you are looking for.  Replace 'ThursdayClass' with the login you need info for.
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/the-sqlcmd-workbench/

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    CREATE TABLE #temp
        (
          SERVER_name SYSNAME NULL ,
          Database_name SYSNAME NULL ,
          UserName SYSNAME ,
          GroupName SYSNAME ,
          LoginName SYSNAME NULL ,
          DefDBName SYSNAME NULL ,
          DefSchemaName SYSNAME NULL ,
          UserID INT ,
          [SID] VARBINARY(85)
        )

    DECLARE @command VARCHAR(MAX)
    --this will contain all the databases (and their sizes!)
    --on a server
    DECLARE @databases TABLE
        (
          Database_name VARCHAR(128) ,
          Database_size INT ,
          remarks VARCHAR(255)
        )
    INSERT  INTO @databases--stock the table with the list of databases
            EXEC sp_databases

    SELECT  @command = COALESCE(@command, '') + '
    USE ' + database_name + '
    insert into #temp (UserName,GroupName, LoginName,
                        DefDBName, DefSchemaName,UserID,[SID])
         Execute sp_helpuser
    UPDATE #TEMP SET database_name=DB_NAME(),
                     server_name=@@ServerName
    where database_name is null
    '
    FROM    @databases
    EXECUTE ( @command )

    SELECT  loginname ,
            UserName ,
            Database_name
    FROM    #temp
    WHERE   LoginName = 'ThursdayClass'
```

Comment: Thanks Taiob, this works well, (I would enclose the database_name column in brackets ('[' and ']')

Answer (score 6):

Try [sp_dbpermissions](http://sqlstudies.com/free-scripts/sp_dbpermissions/). It will probably give you more info than you need but it will do what you want.

Once it's installed run this.

```
sp_dbpermissions @dbname = 'All', @LoginName = 'LoginName'
```

Fair warning at the moment it does a "like" match so if other logins are similar and match then you will see them also.  For example `MyLogin` and `MyLoginForThis` will both match on `MyLogin`.  If that's a problem I have a version that I haven't released yet where you can turn that off.  Let me know and I can email it to you.

Answer (score 4):

Sadly you are going to have to iterate through all of the databases in order to get the information. You'll want to join `sys.database_principals` to `sys.server_principals` for each database matching on the SID.

Don't use `sp_msforeachdb` as it is known to miss databases at times.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a powershell solution:

```
import-module sqlps;

$s = new-object microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server '.'
foreach ($db in $s.Databases | where {$_.IsAccessible -eq $true}) {
   $u = $db.users | where {$_.Login -eq 'foobar'}
   if ($u -ne $null) { #login is mapped to a user in the db
       foreach ($role in $db.Roles) {
           if ($role.EnumMembers() -contains $u.Name) {
               $u | select parent, @{name="role";expression={$role.name}}, name
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for a similar answer and found this: https://www.pythian.com/blog/httpconsultingblogs-emc-comjamiethomsonarchive20070209sql-server-2005_3a00_-view-all-permissions-_2800_2_2900_-aspx/ .  And yes, it uses the dreaded sp_MSforeachDB, but I think that guy gets a bad rap sometimes... ;-)

I'll post the SQL here for easy copy-pasta (I am *NOT* taking credit for this, just making it easily accessible!):

```
DECLARE @DB_Users TABLE (DBName sysname, UserName sysname, LoginType sysname
, AssociatedRole varchar(max), create_date datetime, modify_date datetime)

INSERT @DB_Users
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb
'use [?]
SELECT ''?'' AS DB_Name,
case prin.name when ''dbo'' then prin.name + '' (''
    + (select SUSER_SNAME(owner_sid) from master.sys.databases where name =''?'') + '')''
    else prin.name end AS UserName,
    prin.type_desc AS LoginType,
    isnull(USER_NAME(mem.role_principal_id),'''') AS AssociatedRole, 
    create_date, modify_date
FROM sys.database_principals prin
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_role_members mem
    ON prin.principal_id=mem.member_principal_id
WHERE prin.sid IS NOT NULL and prin.sid NOT IN (0x00)
and prin.is_fixed_role <> 1 AND prin.name NOT LIKE ''##%'''

SELECT dbname, username, logintype, create_date, modify_date,
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(500), associatedrole)
        FROM @DB_Users user2
        WHERE user1.DBName=user2.DBName AND user1.UserName=user2.UserName
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'') AS Permissions_user
FROM @DB_Users user1
WHERE user1.UserName = N'<put your login-name here!>'
GROUP BY dbname, username, logintype, create_date, modify_date
ORDER BY DBName, username
```

Answer (score -1):

Below Query shall return the mappings for the requested DbName

```
SELECT 'DbName', dbPri.name, dbPri1.name
FROM [DbName].sys.database_principals dbPri 
JOIN [DbName].sys.database_role_members dbRoleMem ON dbRoleMem.member_principal_id = 
dbPri.principal_id
JOIN [DbName].sys.database_principals dbPri1  ON dbPri1.principal_id = 
dbRoleMem.role_principal_id
WHERE dbPri.name != 'dbo'
```

Improved Query is below

```
declare @sql varchar(Max)

 set @sql = 'use ? SELECT ''?'', dbPri.name, dbPri1.name
 FROM sys.database_principals dbPri 
 JOIN sys.database_role_members dbRoleMem ON 
 dbRoleMem.member_principal_id = 
 dbPri.principal_id
 JOIN sys.database_principals dbPri1  ON dbPri1.principal_id = 
 dbRoleMem.role_principal_id
 WHERE dbPri.name != ''dbo'''

 EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @sql
```

Comment: Thank you, the goal of this script was to find a mapping for all databases. Your script gives information for just one specific database, not all of them.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I thought It can be repeated.
Now Updated with improved query

Comment: See @Aaron-Bertrand's answer and comment on his thoughts about sp_MSforeachdb.

Answer (score -3):

What about `EXEC master..sp_msloginmappings`?

Comment: Did you check `sp_msloginmappings` is undocumented and unsupported before posting ?