# How do I write an SQL script to copy the securables, memberships and owned schemas of a current database user?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

How do I write an SQL script to copy the securables, memberships and owned schemas of a current database user?

I currently have to repeatedly restore databases on my local machine for development work. I then have to manually add database users to the master level login section so that I can allow my web app to authenticate with the database. I can see that you can right-click on the user -> Script User as -> Create To -> New Query editor window. The resulting SQL does not artificially mimic any of the securables, memberships, or owned schemas.

I already found that you can programmatically add a user to the database that uses the Master login information.

CREATE USER [user_name] FOR LOGIN [user_name] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO

Comment: When you restore database all user permission (at database level) are copied with it. You only have to create login and match `SID` and it should work.  Why do you need to script out user level information?

Comment: First result.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987190/scripting-sql-server-permissions

Comment: [This script will help you](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44339/8783)

Comment: @SqlWorldWide, that ended up helping me connect the dots. I thought You had to start at the login level and have your user created on the database from the master level.

Comment: There are few scripts [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81595/a-query-that-lists-all-mapped-users-for-a-given-login/81599#81599) you can use to match all `sid` after a restore.

Comment: @JonathanFite, that link was directed at stored procedures and not users, but still interesting information

Comment: @Jolley71717 Did you only read the first line of the question? `on stored procedures **and other stuff**` and if you look at the accepted answer it does not do any sort of limits on only stored procedures.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, thank you for pointing that out. I did skim that answer. I went back through and actually ran the code. It does exactly what I was asking for. Thanks for being patient with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you restore a database all the users and privilege assigned to users (including database role membership) from that database get restored at the destination server.  If you already have a login in the destination server with matching Server-Level Identification Number (SID) then you do not have to do anything.

If you do not have a login you will need to create one:

- Copy login from source to destination using [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/918992/how-to-transfer-logins-and-passwords-between-instances-of-sql-server) or [this](https://dbatools.io/functions/copy-sqllogin/).

You have have a login with different SID you can match those using solution from [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81595/a-query-that-lists-all-mapped-users-for-a-given-login/81599#81599).